# Invalid results by summing an array, OpenCL, Interleaved Addressing

Tags: c++, opencl, gpu, reduction

i'm starting to learn OpenCl and as one of the tasks I have to write I program, that sums all elements of an array.

The program is supposed to be simple and I don't know what's wrong with me today, but it's not working. Well, it does, but sometimes it shows wrong results (sometimes doesn't).

The more elements we have, the bigger is the chance to get a wrong result (especially after 16536)
The number of elements always equals to the power of two.

Could someone please tell me, what's wrong here?

The kernel:

```
__kernel void Reduction_InterleavedAddressing(__global uint* array, uint stride)
{
    unsigned int i = get_global_id (0); 
    unsigned int size = get_global_size(0);

    if ((i % stride*2) == 0 && (i + stride)<size){
            array[i]  += array[i+stride];
    }
}
```

Kernel call:

```
    unsigned int stride = 1;
    clErr = clSetKernelArg(m_InterleavedAddressingKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&m_dPingArray);

    for (; stride <= m_N / 2 ; stride*=2){
        clErr = clSetKernelArg(m_InterleavedAddressingKernel, 1, sizeof(cl_int), (void*)&stride);
        clErr = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(CommandQueue, m_InterleavedAddressingKernel, 1, NULL, &globalWorkSize, LocalWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);
        V_RETURN_CL(clErr, "Error executing kernel");
    }
```

Thank your for your tips in advance

Comment: What is LocalWorkSize? Try passing NULL instead. In OpenCL 1.x if you pass a local work size then the global work size must be a multiple of it. Also, this kernel might be good for learning but it's not an efficient reduction operation (as stride increases, fewer and fewer work items actually do anything). To debug your algorithm you could read back the buffer after each iteration to see if the results match what you're expecting.

Comment: You are walking in the cliff with that code, if the work items read and write the same memory inside a single kernel call the results will be wrong for sure.
In my opinion the error is at the global size, the size should reduce with each iteration, and please, leave the local size NULL, since for that code is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answers. I wrote it again, globalWorkSize = number of elements and i divide it by two every time, localSize = NULL and in kernel i rearrange elements after every step (put the at the beginning)

it works better but there are still mistakes :(

Comment: UPDATE: I changed barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) to barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE) and it looks like it works

Answer (score 0):

I testet it. You must set the `stride * 2` to (`stride * 2`)! For my solution it worked well.

```
if ((i % (stride*2)) == 0 && (i + stride) < size) {
    array[i]  += array[i+stride];
}
```